# Use Realm subclass as custom function parameter

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I am using Realm and it has function that take as an argument a class inheriting from `Object` (not `NSObject`), e.g.

```
realm.objects(Class)
```

I want to make a function that also takes `Class` as parameter.

I want make function that will take a class and forward it to Realm's function. I tried something like this, but it doesn't work:

```
func test(type: AnyClass) {
    let realm = ..
    realm.objects(type)
}
```

The Swift compiler reports an error saying that it cannot cast from `AnyClass` to `Object.Type`

I found a similar question here: [Pass a Swift class as parameter, and then call a class method out of it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29712667/pass-a-swift-class-as-parameter-and-then-call-a-class-method-out-of-it/29714287)

But maybe there is a simpler solution that doesn't require protocol implementation for every class? I want the function to make the decision of what to do by itself depending on what class it receives.

I want it to look like `realm.objects(Class)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the same signature: `objects` declaration looks like this:

```
func objects<T: Object>(type: T.Type) -> Results<T>
```

So you need a generic function constraining the type to subclasses of `Realm.Object`:

```
func test<T: Object>(type: T.Type) {
    let realm = ...
    realm.objects(type)
}
```

Then, assuming that your class (`MyClass` in this sample) inherits from `Realm.Object`, you can call it like this:

```
class MyClass: Object {}

test(MyClass)
```

---

If your method takes an object of that type, you can infer the type:

```
func test<T: Object>(element: T) {
    let realm = ...
    realm.objects(T.self)
}
```